# Forcing OSX NSScroller thumb to draw in highlighted form without actually mouse tracking

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm drawing an `NSScroller` into a bitmap. I need to capture it with the thumb highlighted (I'm using `cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:`, but I've tried the separate draw methods into a GC created on the bitmap). I've tried everything I can think of, including setting various values in the (private) `_sFlags2` and `sFlags` `NSScroller` ivars before the draw call. I can't send it events because the scroller isn't actually live.

Eventually I need this to work on 10.6+, but all of my testing so far has been on 10.7+ (which is where the new style scrollbars came in), and I haven't checked 10.6 yet because I'm also using `alignmentRectForFrame:` and haven't faked that out for 10.6 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some quality time spent with [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com)! I found the following solution:

```
[[scrollbar scrollerImp] setShouldDrawRolloverState: YES];
```

Undocumented, but I'm a happy camper!